# ConsoleShell with command argument

Tags: powershell

I have a tool in which I can launch a PowerShell instance using Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleShell.Start(). This works very well except that I cannot run a script by passing it as a -Command parameter.

Simplified the code looks like this

```
string[] psArgs = new[] {"Command", ".\\test.ps1"};

var config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
int i= ConsoleShell.Start(
    config,
    "PSPowerShell",
    "",
    psArgs
);
```

When I use this, PowerShell starts and I get the following output

```
CommandType     Name       Definition
-----------     ----       ----------
ExternalScript  test.ps1   E:\testarea\test.ps1
```

It feels like I'm missing something trivial but I cannot see it...

I've also tried using & but that only gives me the error:

```
Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to pass ampersand as a string.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are telling it to run command, but then you are giving it a script file.

Try changing your first line to this:

```
string[] psArgs = new[] {"-File", ".\\test.ps1"};
```

Comment: This answer work and made me realize that I've missed the -. Changing the first line to: `string[] psArgs = new[] {"-Command", ".\\test.ps1"};` and it works just fine.